# how to use queryIntentActivityOptions() method

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-gallery, android-package-managers

Am trying to create a dialog that shows all applications in a user phone that can be used to select a picture from the storage or take one using the camera. below are my two intents that am planning to use.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");

Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

The best way i have found to populate my listview in my customized dialog with applications that can perform the above actions is to use `queryIntentActivityOptions()` method but am stucked.

- i have never used it before and i don't know whether am doing it the right way
- i don't know how i will populate my listview with the gotten applications from  `queryIntentActivityOptions()` method.
- How to implement `onItemClickListener` in my listview which is in my customized dialog.

This is my method that contain the dialog. **please i have researched but haven't found a good tutorial to guide me on how i can implement** `queryIntentActivityOptions()`

```
private void acquirePicture(){
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");

    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    WMLP.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about_dialog);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    ListView lv=(ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();

    List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivityOptions(
this.getComponentName(),new Intent[]{photoPickerIntent,takePicture},
null,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    Collections.sort(launchables,
            new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

    appAdapter=new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ResolveInfo launchable=appAdapter.getItem(position);
            ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
            ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                    activity.name);
            //I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO NEXT OR WHETHER AM DOING IT
             THE CORRECT WAY
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}

class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> {
    private PackageManager pm=null;

    AppAdapter(PackageManager pm, List<ResolveInfo> apps) {
        super(Custom_chooser.this, R.layout.row, apps);
        this.pm=pm;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView==null) {
            convertView=newView(parent);
        }

        bindView(position, convertView);

        return(convertView);
    }

    private View newView(ViewGroup parent) {
        return(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false));
    }

    private void bindView(int position, View row) {
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

        label.setText(getItem(position).loadLabel(pm));

        ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).loadIcon(pm));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works well.

Comment: @tinysunlight   i have problem understanding `queryIntentActivityOptions()`. expecially 2nd  and 3rd parameters. do you understand it well?

Answer (score 1):

check the below working code to open, Camera and browse through gallery at once.

```
 // Picks Camera first.
final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
        captureIntent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
  final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
  final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
  intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
          res.activityInfo.name));
  intent.setPackage(packageName);
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
  cameraIntents.add(intent);
}

final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

// Chooser of filesystem options.
final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent,
        "Select Image from");

// Add the camera options.
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
        cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

This will help you.!!

Reference links and tutorials [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286447/queryintentactivityoptions-not-working/34287834#34287834).

Answer (score 0):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ResolveInfo launchable=appAdapter.getItem(position);
                   String packageName = launchable.activityInfo.packageName;
        String className = launchable.activityInfo.name;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
        intent.setComponent(cn);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



 /**
     * Retrieve a set of activities that should be presented to the user as
     * similar options.  This is like {@link #queryIntentActivities}, except it
     * also allows you to supply a list of more explicit Intents that you would
     * like to resolve to particular options, and takes care of returning the
     * final ResolveInfo list in a reasonable order, with no duplicates, based
     * on those inputs.
     *
     * @param caller The class name of the activity that is making the
     *               request.  This activity will never appear in the output
     *               list.  Can be null.
     * @param specifics An array of Intents that should be resolved to the
     *                  first specific results.  Can be null.
     * @param intent The desired intent as per resolveActivity().
     * @param flags Additional option flags.  The most important is
     * {@link #MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY}, to limit the resolution to only
     * those activities that support the {@link android.content.Intent#CATEGORY_DEFAULT}.
     *
     * @return A List&lt;ResolveInfo&gt; containing one entry for each matching
     *         Activity. These are ordered first by all of the intents resolved
     *         in <var>specifics</var> and then any additional activities that
     *         can handle <var>intent</var> but did not get included by one of
     *         the <var>specifics</var> intents.  If there are no matching
     *         activities, an empty list is returned.
     *
     * @see #MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY
     * @see #GET_INTENT_FILTERS
     * @see #GET_RESOLVED_FILTER
     */
    public abstract List<ResolveInfo> queryIntentActivityOptions(
            ComponentName caller, Intent[] specifics, Intent intent, int flags);
```

Comment: can you please elaborate this `@param specifics An array of Intents that should be resolved to the
     *                  first specific results.  Can be null.` **and this**  `@param intent The desired intent as per resolveActivity().`

Comment: I think @return is more important.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a good understanding  of `queryIntentActivityOptions()` method of class PackageManager.

**QueryIntentActivityOptions**(ComponentName caller, Intent[] specifics,Intent intent, int flags)

- **caller** - This is the name of the class you are currently calling this method from. **usually we use** `this.getComponentName` as the value for this parameter.
- **specifics** - This is an array of intents that you want to be first resolved. for your case, you can put any of the two intents you have. i.e `photoPickerIntent` or `takePictureIntent` **like this**

  `new Intent[] {takePicture}`

  **NOTE:** this parameter value can be null if you have only one intent. in that case, i think it would be better to use `QueryIntentActivities`. but for your case, since you have more than one intent, continue using this method.
- **intent** - Here you place your desired intent. i.e **between the two intents that you have, the one you desided not to put in the array because you so it as the most important one**

  **NOTE:** this parameter value cannot be null. putting a null value will throw a NullPointerException!
- **flags** - This is like a filter or extra that you want to be included **in any of the resolved activites returned by this method.**

  - **PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY** - puting this option will filter the resolved activities and select the activities that belong to default applications in your device.e.g if `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` can be resolved by two apps, one which is the default and the other is third party one, e.g you downloaded it, one the default will be selected
  - **PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS** - this option return information about all the intent filters that the resolved app can handle. e.g you can have an app that resolved `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and yet it can also resolve `ACTION_PICK`
  - **PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER** - this option return the intent filter that each of the apps in the list resolved

**A WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");

PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();


List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivityOptions(
 this.getComponentName(),new Intent[]{takePicture},
 photoPickerIntent,PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);

  Collections.sort(launchables,
    new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));
```

**You can then populate your listview using the above list of lauchaubles**

```
 ListView lv=(ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

 AppAdapter appAdapter=new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);

 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ResolveInfo launchable=appAdapter.getItem(position);
    ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
    ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
            activity.name);

 IntentFilter filter = launchable.filter;
        if(filter.actionsIterator() != null){
            Iterator<String > actions = filter.actionsIterator();
        }

        int actioncode;
        Intent  intent = new Intent();
        Uri uri;
        if(filter.hasAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK)){
            actioncode = 1;
            uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            intent.setData(uri);
        }else{
            actioncode = 0;
        }
        intent.setComponent(name);
        startActivityForResult(intent,actioncode);

}
});

 }

class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> {

private PackageManager pm=null;

AppAdapter(PackageManager pm, List<ResolveInfo> apps) {
super(Custom_chooser.this, R.layout.row, apps);
this.pm=pm;
}

 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
if (convertView==null) {
    convertView=newView(parent);
}

bindView(position, convertView);

return(convertView);
}

private View newView(ViewGroup parent) {
return(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false));
}

private void bindView(int position, View row) {
TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

label.setText(getItem(position).loadLabel(pm));

ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).loadIcon(pm));
}
}
```