# queryIntentActivityOptions not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-dialog, android-package-managers

I am trying to create a dialog that shows all applications in a user phone that can be used to select a picture from the storage or take one using the camera.

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34284223/146325).

The best way I have found to populate my listview in my customized dialog with applications that can perform the above actions is to use `queryIntentActivityOptions()` method but it's not working. **my listview isn't been populated with apps that can be used to access an image or take one using the camera**.

```
private void acquirePicture(){
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");

    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    WMLP.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about_dialog);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    ListView lv=(ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();

    List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivityOptions(
this.getComponentName(),new Intent[]{takePicture},
photoPickerIntent,0);

    Collections.sort(launchables,
            new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

    appAdapter=new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ResolveInfo launchable=appAdapter.getItem(position);
            ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
            ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                    activity.name);
            //I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO NEXT OR WHETHER AM DOING IT
             THE CORRECT WAY
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}

class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> {
    private PackageManager pm=null;

    AppAdapter(PackageManager pm, List<ResolveInfo> apps) {
        super(Custom_chooser.this, R.layout.row, apps);
        this.pm=pm;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView==null) {
            convertView=newView(parent);
        }

        bindView(position, convertView);

        return(convertView);
    }

    private View newView(ViewGroup parent) {
        return(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false));
    }

    private void bindView(int position, View row) {
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

        label.setText(getItem(position).loadLabel(pm));

        ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).loadIcon(pm));
    }
}
```

**RESULT(empty dialog)**

[image: empty dialog]

**EDIT**

```
 List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivityOptions(
this.getComponentName(),new Intent[]{takePicture},
photoPickerIntent,0);
```

Comment: wondered, why you are using the custom dialog to show installed apps. It is default that they will all show in a dialog.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan how then can i show a list of apps that can perform **the two actions in the same dialog ? i havent seen an intent that can accomodiate two actions in it's parameters**

Comment: what are all the actions required .? 1. want to open camera or 2. pick from the local storage correct.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan  am creating an app where user with click of a button, can provide an image either from the storage or take one using camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the correct adapter in your listview

**Your code**

```
 List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivityOptions(
 this.getComponentName(),new Intent[]{takePicture},
 photoPickerIntent,0);

Collections.sort(launchables,
        new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

appAdapter=new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);

lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Correct way**

```
List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivityOptions(
 this.getComponentName(),new Intent[]{takePicture},
 photoPickerIntent,0);

Collections.sort(launchables,
        new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

appAdapter=new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);

lv.setAdapter(appAdapter);
```

**Note the difference  in**

```
lv.setAdapter(appAdapter);
```

**Result**

[image: after correcting error]

Answer (score 2):

Hope if i am correct you are looking for something like below, refer screenshot. Opening Camera and Browse Files options in the single dialog.

```
 // Picks Camera first.
final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
        captureIntent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
  final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
  final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
  intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
          res.activityInfo.name));
  intent.setPackage(packageName);
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
  cameraIntents.add(intent);
}

final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

// Chooser of filesystem options.
final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent,
        "Select Image from");

// Add the camera options.
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
        cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

This will help you.!!

[image: Screenshot from lollipop and jelly bean[![][1]]]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ8BH.png)

[Tutorial for how to work with camera](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/)

[Tutorial for how to browse and select file from the storage.](http://codetheory.in/android-pick-select-image-from-gallery-with-intents/)

[Selecting image from internal storage](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-pick-image-from-gallery/)

Comment: brother, this is it !!  :). however, because i know my boss will need a customized dialog, with your example, i was able to correct my problem. the issue was **i was passing the wrong adapter to my listview**. after passing the correct adapter, my custom dialog was populated. **however** i still have a question. have you ever used `packageManager.queryIntentActivities`?

Comment: i have never used it and  am douting my implementation. it's working. **but i haven't understood 2nd and 3rd parameters my implementation is guesswork** [CLICK HERE](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivityOptions%28android.content.ComponentName,%20android.content.Intent[],%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Comment: please if possible tell me if i have implemented `packageManager.queryIntentActivities` the correct way

Comment: i have edited my question. please see my edit which shows my implementation of `packageManager.queryIntentActivities`

Comment: added some reference links to work further with what you have...!!

Comment: great tutorial. i highly appreciate your help my brother.

Comment: Men, i don't know who downvoted your good answer and links. i tried to upvote it again but i cant since i had already upvoted it before

Comment: cool no problem :) ..!! may be my answer was not be good enough to understand..!! @gikarasojokinene

Comment: yah to the one who downvoted. but to me everything was crystal clear. lets hope things will get better. sometimes i also find myself in same situation but hope for the best.