# Dialog like complete action using

Tags: android, android-studio, dialog

I want to create a dialog like this:

[image: required dialog click here]

I need to create the dialog when user clicks on the profile image like given in link. Current I'm doing this

```
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Gallery", "Camera", "Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            if (items[item].equals("Gallery")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp1.jpg");
                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CODE);

            } else if (items[item].equals("Camera")) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, GALLERY_CODE);

            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

I dont know how to do as the design given please help me on this.

Comment: Create your own custom dialog  like extend activity extend Dialog.

Comment: Create layout containing button as you have shown in image, create PopupWindow, inflate your customview and set that as popupwindow view and show it as either alert window or as simple popup window as per your requirements. Done :)

Comment: I can create that but how can i get the image of camera and gallery app icons?

Comment: You mean u need system icons for camera and gallery ??? Or else you can always reach out your designer I guess. I dont see any intent that will ask the system to show alert like that :o So its always you who has to do that :|

Comment: do you want to open the default dialog which asks gallery as well as camera ?

Comment: check my answer below..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can achieve this.

1. Using Custom Alert dialog.
2. Using Intent by query intent activities.

By default, Android doesn't show the option to open camera and gallery in a single shot. But doing some tricks will help to achieve this.

Refer the below code which is used to display Camera and Gallery browse options in a single default dialog.

```
// Picks Camera first.
final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
        captureIntent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
  final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
  final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
  intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
          res.activityInfo.name));
  intent.setPackage(packageName);
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
  cameraIntents.add(intent);
}

final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

// Chooser of filesystem options.
final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent,
        "Select Image from");

// Add the camera options.
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
        cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

Already answered here for same type of issue. !! 
--> [queryIntentActivityOptions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286447/queryintentactivityoptions-not-working/34287834#34287834)

Hope this helps you,